# Pygame. Windows 10. Creates additional windows after loop.run_in_executor using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, windows, pygame, python-3.6, python-asyncio

#### Environment where issues is reproduced:

OS: Windows 10 (Host)

CPU: 8

Python: 3.6.6

pygame version: 1.9.4

"builder": cx_Freeze version 5.1.1

#### Environment where issues is NOT reproduced:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (guest, virtualbox)

CPU: 4

Python: 3.6.6

pygame version: 1.9.4

"builder": cx_Freeze version 5.1.1

#### Script

```
import asyncio
import pygame
import multiprocessing

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def init():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 700), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    return screen, clock


def fast_cpu_blocked():
    print("blocked is run")
    i = 1
    while 1:
        i += 1
        if i > 100000000:
            print("blocked is finished")
            return i


executor_threads = ThreadPoolExecutor(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
executor_processes = ProcessPoolExecutor(multiprocessing.cpu_count())


async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    cpu_run = False
    screen, clock = init()
    while 1:
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, clock.tick, 60)
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        txt_surface = pygame.font.Font(None, 18).render(
            "FPS: {}".format(int(clock.get_fps())), True, pygame.Color('grey'))
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        if not cpu_run:
            print("RUN CPU TASK")
            cpu_run = True
            loop.run_in_executor(executor_processes, fast_cpu_blocked)
            print("FINISH CPU TASK")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start())
```

#### Issue:

When `loop.run_in_executor(executor_processes, fast_cpu_blocked)` is executed it produces multiple windows of application(just black window, without any rendered context). 


It doesn't happen when use `executor_threads` instead of `executor_processes`. But anyway I need `executor_processes`, so it is just a fact.

#### Logs in Windows:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
RUN CPU TASK
FINISH CPU TASK
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
blocked is run
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
blocked is finished
```

#### Logs in Ubuntu:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
RUN CPU TASK
FINISH CPU TASK
blocked is run
blocked is finished
```

#### Question:

How to fix/avoid/hack producing multiple windows on Windows system.

And why it happens?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you are running? eg. where did `wololo` come from in the windows logs? Regarding processes, Linux and Windows create them differently. Windows has to "spawn" the executor sub-processes from scratch (whereas Linux would "fork" the process). So each child does `import pygame`, which is why you get the print outs `cores+1` times. But only the line `screen = ...` should create a screen and as is, that only gets run in the main process. I don't get multiple windows on my windows machine, so I have to guess that you've left something out by accident.

Comment: I've recheckd code. It's same now. (difference was in `print(wololo)`).
Interesting fact: when I run script via pycharm (on Windows) I don't see multiple windows issue, but logs still there.
When I build it using cz_Freeze - issue is reproduces on Windows.

Comment: Does it help if you move `import pygame` to the inside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block?

Comment: no, it didn't help. And it is not a good option, because file could require pygame module.

Comment: Tested after compiling with cx_Freeze - same effect - multiple windows for each process.

Comment: Do you know which line of your code actually leads to the display of "Hello from the pygame community"?

Comment: when `import pygame` line executes. But for some reason, even if put this import into `init` and `start` functions and delete from top of the file -> it anyway will be printed in new processes :/

Comment: It's probably related to this. You need to call [`multiprocessing.freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support).

Comment: @Dunes great! it works! I'd like to close(resolve) this question. So could you please leave same answer and I'll mark is as resolved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating an exe for Windows using [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and using some form of multi-processing (eg. `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` you need to bootstrap your exe for multi-processing as the very first thing you do. You do this simply by calling [`multiprocessing.freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) as the very first thing inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.